# Are there any bottled South Korean craft beers?

Tags: breweries, craft-beers

Are there any South Korean craft breweries who bottle their beers?

Bonus question: Where (in Seoul) can my friend obtain some?

Answer (score 3):

Ratebeer has list of breweries in South Korea. I see there are some in Seoul and the images show bottles, so I assume that they bottle.

Go to [RateBeer](http://www.ratebeer.com/search.php) and in the Brewer Search area select the country. (I would have liked to give a result link, but ratebeer hides them).

Answer (score 1):

Here you can find several places: [Good Beer Hunting](http://goodbeerhunting.com/blog/2012/10/7/setting-seoul-on-fire-48-hours-in-the-heart-of-south-korea).

e.g.: Craftworks
[img]https://i.stack.imgur.com/WPq1g.png

[image: Seoul]

Comment: I don't see any photos or references to bottled Korean craft beer (only macros)... Could you quote the relevant section(s)?